# Generate Partition of integer into k different integers (C++)

Tags: c++

I have problem with the constraint

1. I have to partition it to "exact" k "different" integers

e.g. 10 = 1+2+7 -> valid
10 = 2+2+6 -> invalid

2. I don't want to print them, I want to store them in to vectors or something

I am thinking of recursive solution, but still can't come up with a efficient way to store them...(the solution I found can only print it)

And I think it should store in vector<vector>

the struct should be like this?

Partition(){
....
....
}

Partition_main(){
...
Partition()
....
}

Comment: Declare a global array and push and pop the element that you are trying during the recursion.

Comment: what did you implement? where is your code where you tried? what were the problems you faced ? instead of sharing the problem share the issues problems you faced during implementation

Comment: sorry, but I can't even write a code to run, since the constraint is too many.

Comment: omg starboy_jb thank you, I was stuck at there, I forgot I have to pop out the previous element when I finish this iteration

Comment: Showing your implementation to print can help us to show you how to transform it in code to collect result.

Comment: Is there any contrain between the number N and the decomposition k? For example N = 6 = 1 + 2 + 3. it is not possible to decompose 6 into 4 different integers.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, the problem is to enumerate all the solutions.
This can be done by a DFS.
In the following code, the DFS is implemented with a help of a FIFO (i.e. a `std::queue`).

The little trick is, for a given candidate at a given step, to calculate the minimum
sum that can be obtained in the next steps.
If this minimum sum is larger than `n`, then we can stop the research in this direction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <cassert>

struct Parti {
    std::vector<int> v;
    int sum = 0;
};

std::vector<std::vector<int>> get_partitions (int n, int k) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> result;
    std::queue<Parti> fifo;
    Parti start;
    fifo.push(start);
    while (!fifo.empty()) {
        Parti elt = fifo.front();
        fifo.pop();
        int sum = elt.sum;
        int remain = k-elt.v.size();
        if (remain == 1) {
            int last = n - sum;
            if (k > 1) assert (last > elt.v.back());
            elt.v.push_back(last);
            result.push_back (elt.v);
            continue;
        }
        int i;
        if (elt.v.size() == 0) i = 1;
        else i = elt.v.back() + 1;
        
        while (true) {
            int min_sum = sum + remain*(2*i + remain - 1)/2;
            if (min_sum > n) break;
            Parti new_elt = elt;
            new_elt.v.push_back(i);  
            new_elt.sum += i;
            fifo.push (new_elt);
            ++i;
        };
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int n = 15;
    int k = 4;
    auto res = get_partitions (n, k);
    if (res.size() == 0) {
        std::cout << "no partition possible\n";
        return 0;
    }   

    for (const auto& v: res) {
        std::cout << n << " = ";
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << v[i];
            if (i == v.size()-1) {
                std::cout << "\n";
            } else {
                std::cout << " + ";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```